# Error: unable to spawn process (Argument list too long) Xcode 10.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

> Error Log:
>   PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Check\ Pods\ Manifest.lock /Users/../Script-A..B8.sh (in target: C..r)
>       cd /Projects/...
>       /bin/sh -c /Users/../Script-A..B8.sh
>   error: unable to spawn process (Argument list too long)**

I am getting this error while creating an Archive from Xcode (10.1).  My build succeeds. I encountered this error after installing below mentioned pods,

**pod 'Firebase/Analytics'**

**pod 'Firebase/Messaging'**

My Xcode project is a multi target and multi configuration project managed using xconfig file.

I tried disintegrating, installing, updating pod again and again, but no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enable Legacy System for workspace setting
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this kind of helped to get to the root of the problem and fix it. The issue was Compile Sources was having duplicate files and also if we add GoogleService-Info.plist directly to the respective target New Build System cannot Archive the application, in short Cocoapods and New build system don’t work well together.

Comment: @Ajay: How did you got this option?

Comment: @JayprakashDubey In Workspace setting under File Menu of Xcode

Comment: This however hinders the push notifications from One Signal